# Neon lighting effect animation, how to?

Tags: animation

I was asked to inherit this project at work and re-do the animation as the background and lighting structure shape changed. I was going to use Motion 5 or After effect, but I was curious if I could it in Blender as well. If possible I want to do it in Blender as I would like to take it as a learning opportunity. I am new to Blender, so I am not sure if this is achievable in Blender.

Please see the below link for the existing animation:
https://vimeo.com/281395110

My main question is:

1. how to make neon lighting effect that constantly changes color in Blender?
2. how to combine background image with lighting structure?

I have no idea where to start, tried to find some tutorials but no luck. I would appreciate your help!

Thank you.

Comment: It is achievable in Blender, but. First of all, please ask only one question per post. Secondly, be more precise. There are couple different things going on on the clip. Basically each shape has different animation scheme. The best way would be to pick one, post it as a screenshot (or short gif) and be more descriptive.

Comment: A colour swatch can be animated the same as any single value in blender.

Comment: I will check Edge glow thread! It is good that it is possible to do it in Blender, I started to watch some beginner's tutorials. I will post more questions as I go along, thanks to everyone who replied to the post.